# Store invalid decimal value in C# decimal

Tags: c#, .net

I have a C#/.NET library that calls a C library. The C library has a C function that returns the current date and time in a byte array containing the characters for the date and time numbers. I create a C# delegate for the C function, in order to call it in C#.

If DateTime.Now returns `2001-02-03 04:05:06.789123`, the C function would return `2001020304050678`.

In order for my delegate to work, I have to supply a `decimal` for the C function to populate (I have tried many others, including `byte[]` and `char[]`, but the C function fails to populate them with access violation).

```
internal delegate void DatetimeDelegate(ref decimal dateTimeString);
```

I call the delegate as so:

```
decimal dateTimeDecimal = 0.0M;
dateTimeDelegate(ref dateTimeDecimal);
... // I can add the rest of my conversion code here if needed, but I don't consider it relevant to my question
```

And the resulting `decimal` is not a valid `decimal` value, but it is accepted. No exception is thrown, and I can work with the bytes in `dateTimeString` even if it is invalid and cannot be operated on arithmetically.

Now, for tests, I want to create a mock for my `DatetimeDelegate` which does the opposite. But once I've produced the bytes I want to put into a `decimal`, I'm not allowed to do that, as it's not a valid `decimal` value.

Is there any way to bypass the check for a valid `decimal` value in a `decimal` constructor and create a `decimal` anyway to store the bytes?

Comment: There's a considerable amount of missing information here.  You didn't show us code that demonstrates why `char[]` and `byte[]` didn't work, and we don't know what you mean by "invalid." (out of range?)  In effect, what we have here is an [X Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Use a string instead of decimal.  Decimal is stored as binary and there will be a slight error in converting between decimal and binary.  Other solution is to convert date to a long which is count of 100nsec from 1/1/01.

Comment: Also, you didn't specify how your C api looks like. I doubt you need a delegate there.

Comment: I don't get the delegate-point. You don't need a delegate to call a native function. Just use `extern`.

Comment: What is the declaration of the C function, as in, it's P/Invoke signature? It would seem the function should work if passed a `byte*` pointing to 16 bytes of room, but a `ref decimal` is undoubtedly the clunkiest way to do that. A `byte[]` should work, provided you initialize the argument first with a `new byte[16]`. A `char[]` will also work, but then you'd need an explicit `CharSet.Ansi` declaration in the `DllImport`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attempt to make passing a `byte[]` - or a `string` - work instead.

As mentioned in the comments, the current solution has 16 bytes allocated on the stack, and `ref decimal` passes a pointer to those 16 bytes. It is better (for clarity, for maintainability, in case you need more than 16 bytes) to pass something else which has enough room instead.

If the error is access violation, it sounds like you may be passing `ref byte[]` instead of `byte[]`. It becomes a "pointer to a pointer". Using `byte[]` should be enough. You may also need to pass another parameter to describe how many items are in the array, since in C, `byte[]` "decays" to a pointer, which does not have length information. You can also marshal a string.

You will also need to work out who allocates the memory for the string or array. If the C side allocates the memory, it doesn't then get to free the memory unless you also call into it again with another function.

For more information, [see the P/Invoke documentation, starting here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshalling-data-with-platform-invoke). In my experience, it is poorly laid out and doesn't have a good bunch of examples for simple cases but it is at least authoritative.

Comment: My problem was indeed that I sent ref byte[] instead of just byte[]. I feel stupid now. Thank you very much!